# Getting JS errors on live site

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.2.6, lazyload, owl-carousel

http://35.178.2.150/rep/india please hit this URL and inspect it, and help me if you can.

Comment: why not redeploy your static view files and check if those errors you are talking still exists. By the way, posting links instead of describing your specific issue or problem seems to be so lazy

Comment: done with it, but still the same error

Comment: Are you implementing any external js

Comment: you should run setup upgrade before redeploying static contents

Comment: This is nothing related to deploying again or upgrade issue

Comment: @FarhanAli did you remove the old static content first? run `rm -rf pub/static/*` in the magento root then deploy again `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area frontend`

Comment: @Zankar i am also done with it, still having same issue,

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran yes i have my custom.js

Comment: this is requirejs issue, your implementation must be wrong it seems, wait let me answer to it.

Comment: yes you are right, but what should i do? I don't know who to implement it.

Comment: but everything is running prefectly on local, but facing issues on live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file path for your js should be here Vendor_Modulename/web/js/myfile.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
         'myfile': "Vendor_Modulename/js/myfile"
      },   
    shim: {
    'myfile': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
  }
}
```

After that you can load the js inside your views like

```
<srcipt>
 require(["jquery","myfile"],function($,myfile){
     $(document).ready(function(){
        //call your js here...
     })
 })
</script>
```

If still your js is not working you can add setTimeOut js built in function which can load js after few couple of seconds of your body loading.

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Actually the best solution for you is to load your js after your body loading. You can also use (document).ready or (window).load as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add an external JS in the following way :

Try this,

Add your custom js in the following path.

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/nameofjs.js

then you need to add **requirejs-config.js** to the following path.

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

then add the following code in it

```
 var config = {
    paths: {            
            'your_js_name' : 'js/nameofjs', // loadcustomjs is an name and it can anything in lowercase
        },                                                                
    shim: {
    'your_js_name': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
  }
};
```

and in the phtml which loads in a page or wherever you want to load this js, add the below code in it.

```
require(['jquery','your_js_name'],function($) {
$(window).load(function () {
     /*alert('load from external jquery');*/
});});
```

Hope this helps and this is correct way to load any custom js in M2 as far as I know.

Peace :)